# Python Error:AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tim'

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, attributeerror

Here I am trying to create tim as a list of objects of class TT in `__init__` method and in main method I want to invoke `initialize_population` method for each object in tim list in multiple of for looping.

But i get error below. Here's the code:

```
class TT(object):         
    def __init__(self):
        self.fitness=0
        self.tt_number=0
        self.cube=[[[[[0 for i in range(lecturer)]for j in range(days)]for k in range(clas)]for l in range(periods)]for m in range(subjects)]
        self.tim=[TT() for i in range(initial_population)]

    def main(self):
        count=-1
        num=input("Enter Number:-")
        for i in range(initial_population):
            count+=1
            self.tim[i].initialize_population(i)
            self.tim[i].create_population()
        cross_over(tim,count,class_subject_mapping,0)
        return 0


if __name__== "__main__":
    # main(1)
```

**Error:**

```
Python Error:AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tim'
```

Comment: Sounds like you're calling the *main* function with an integer argument.  Since you don't show the call to the *main* function, we can't say much more.

Comment: Your `main` is a function, not a member of `TT`. You call it with the integer `1` and then expect that integer to be the `self` of an instance of `TT`. You need to make that `main` a method and write different code that creates a `TT` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `def main(self)` wasn't indented inside `class TT`, it is just a regular function, not a method. You call it with `1` which is the local variable `self` and things go bad from there. I'm taking a wild guess that you want to feed a number to the class instance after its been instantiated, so I renamed that function to `run`, indented it to be a method and wrote a different `main` to prompt the user. Notice I always use 4 spaces. Not 2 for the method defs (which makes it hard to spot the very error you have!).

I can't guarantee this is what you really intended and the code still has other issues, but this is a start

```
class TT(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.fitness=0
      self.tt_number=0
      self.cube=[[[[[0 for i in range(lecturer)]
          for j in range(days)]
          for k in range(clas)]
          for l in range(periods)]
          for m in range(subjects)]
      self.tim=[TT() for i in range(initial_population)]

    def run(self, num):
        count=-1
        for i in range(initial_population):
            count+=1
            self.tim[i].initialize_population(i)
            self.tim[i].create_population()
        cross_over(self.tim, count, class_subject_mapping, 0)
        return 0

def main():
    num=input("Enter Number:-")
    tt = TT()
    tt.run(num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```